# Select/Output unique values

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I need to loop through an XML document (no problem over there) and check if a value that i find is already in a (a) tag in a div in my XSL document that i am generating, only if the value is not in that (a) tag i should create a new (a) tag for it and put in in the div that i am checking...
Any one knows how to do it dynamically in XSLT?

```
<div id="tags"><span class="l_cap">&#160;</span>
<a href="#" class="current">all</a>
<xsl:for-each select="root/nodes/node/data/genres">
  <xsl:for-each select="value">
    **<xsl:if test="not(contains())">**
      <a  href="#"><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></a>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

sorry for before, what i am trying to do is: in the if statement, check if the current value is already exist in the div if not, add it, if is, don't do anything...

10x again

Comment: Please post your XSLT, the XML coming in and a sample of the output you want.

Comment: What do you mean by `in a <a> tag`? In the element's text? In a specific attribute?

Comment: Your question is unclear. All the task one can understand you need are posible, but we need a reduce input sample an a desired output to define your requeriments.

Comment: It is absolutely not possible to guess what you want to be done. You must post an example: XML document (as small as possible) and what you want the result of the transformation to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create a distinct list of all of the "genres" in your list.

Assuming a data structure which looks a bit like this:

```
<root>
<nodes>
    <node>
        <data>
            <genres>
                <value>One</value>
                <value>Two</value>
                <value>Two</value>
                <value>Three</value>
                <value>Two</value>
            </genres>
        </data>
    </node>
</nodes>
</root>
```

And a stylesheet which looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="genres" match="value" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <div>
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/nodes/node/data/genres/value">
          <xsl:if test="generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('genres', .)[1])">
              <a href="#"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you will end up with something like this:

```
<div>
<a href="#">One</a>
<a href="#">Two</a>
<a href="#">Three</a>
</div>
```

This is a fairly standard XSLT 1.0 technique. It uses keys (described here: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html ) to create a sort of index of all the /root/nodes/node/data/genres/value entries. Then it loops through all of the entries, but only prints the first one of each type. The end result is that each value will only be output once.

Comment: 10x, i did it with JS, but this is much better, 10x :-)